# Cant override a:active in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, stylesheet, user-agent

I have a footer-menu, structure goes like this:

```
<div class="footer-menu">
<nav>
  <a href="#home"><div class="button"><span class="active">Home</span></div></a>
  <div class="divider"> | </div>
  <a href="#katalog"><div class="button">Catalog</div></a>
  <div class="divider"> | </div> 
  <a href="#onas"><div class="button">Abous us</div></a>
  <div class="divider"> | </div>
  <a href="#novinky"><div class="button">News</div></a>
</nav>
</div>
```

and then I have the CSS rules to override colors:

```
.footer-menu a, .footer-menu a:visited,
.footer-menu a:hover, .footer-menu a:active{
  text-decoration: none;
  color #686868 !important;
}
```

Everything goes fine, except one thing - :active color gets overriden (even when I added !important), by google-chrome-agent-style (to some ugly red :( ):

```
a:-webkit-any-link:active {
      color: -webkit-activelink;
}
```

There is a partial solution in wraping the link text by span and give it a class (like Home) or you can "force-override" user agent style

```
a:-webkit-any-link:active {
      color: #686868; /* or any other color*/
}
```

**but is there a way to somehow turn-off the user-agent-style?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if its just a typo but you need a `:` after color. I was getting the red initially but the colon seemed to work for me.

Comment: Oh my god I was looking there like 1000times and didnt catch it, thank you catcher ! :) (It was really a typo x) I went fully retard)